# Calling Ti.App.getArguments() crashes app when launched via new App Shortcuts

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, 3dtouch

I am testing out the new support for Application Shortcuts as announced on the forums here: http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/11/ios-9-3d-touch-sample-app/

I have the shortcuts showing when I press on the app icon - perfect.

However as soon as the app launches it crashes. And the reason is that when the app is launched or resumed I perform some checks for incoming parameters using the Ti.App.getArguments().

And this bug is basically rendering the new 3D Touch features released in November last year completely useless for my live app.

I reported this issue on JIRA last month but it is still sitting in the Inbox and not getting any attention.

How do I get some attention on this bug? At least to get it acknowledged and out of the Inbox?

Here is the ticket in JIRA:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-3428

Comment: Can you share some code of how you do this parameter check?

Comment: I see the ticket is being triaged and last activity was 1 week ago. Please be patient as we're currently preparing for 5.3 release which takes up a lot of resources. We'll continue to look into the linked ticket.

Comment: @AlbertoPastrolin the JIRA ticket contains a full example.

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator good to know thank you.